# How to iterate over some lists for my coding exercice

Tags: python

Hope u can help me w/ this python function:

```
def comparapal(lista):#lista is a list of lists where each list has 4 elements
  listaPalabras=[]
  for item in lista:
     if item[2] in eagles_dict.keys():# filter the list if the 3rd element corresponds to the key in the dictionary
        listaPalabras.append([item[1],item[2]]) #create a new list with elements 2 and 3
```

The listaPalabras result:

```
[
   ['bien', 'NP00000'],
   ['gracia', 'NCFP000'],
   ['estar', 'VAIP1S0'],
   ['bien', 'RG'],
   ['huevo', 'NCMS000'],
   ['calcio', 'NCMS000'],
   ['leche', 'NCFS000'],
   ['proteina', 'NCFS000'],
   ['francisco', 'NP00000'],
   ['ya', 'RG'],
   ['ser', 'VSIS3S0'],
   ['cosa', 'NCFS000']
]
```

My question is: How can I compare the 1st element of each list so that if the word is the same, compare their tags which is the 2nd element.

Sorry for being ambiguous, the fuunction has to return a list of lists w/ 3 elements: the word, the tag and the number of occurrences of each word. But in order to count the words I need to compare the word w/ others and if there exists 2 or more words alike, then compare the tags to chk the difference. If the tags are different then count the words separately.

result -> [['bien', 'NP00000',1],['bien', 'RG',1]] -> two same words but counted separately by the comparison of the tags 
Thanks in advance:

Comment: Do you want to sort the list using those comparison?

Comment: if you want to sort this list by first and then second element, just do `sorted(<your list name>)`

Comment: Thks Roman and Rohit, but I want to compare the 1st element of each list so that if they are the same, then compare their tags which r the 2nd element of each list to chk if they are completely different

Comment: Right, but what do you want to actually do with this information? Make a sorted list? Group the items? What? simplying `sorted` will sort by first key, then second, so they will be implicitly grouped.

Comment: The result will be a list of lists that contains 3 elements: the word, the tag, and the number of occurrences of each word(that's why I need to compare their tags if the word exists more than once to see if they are completely different and count them properly ). Sort is not important thou, I think the title of my question is not clear... :(

Comment: @JPP You need to give some example output. Do you want to count the number of identical (word,tag) pairs, or do you want one triple for each (word,tag) pair with the same count for the number of occurrences of word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import collections
inlist = [
   ['bien', 'NP00000'],
   ['gracia', 'NCFP000'],
   ['estar', 'VAIP1S0'],
   ['bien', 'RG'],
   ['huevo', 'NCMS000'],
   ['calcio', 'NCMS000'],
   ['leche', 'NCFS000'],
   ['proteina', 'NCFS000'],
   ['francisco', 'NP00000'],
   ['ya', 'RG'],
   ['ser', 'VSIS3S0'],
   ['cosa', 'NCFS000']
]
[(a,b,v) for (a,b),v in collections.Counter(map(tuple,inlist)).iteritems()]
#=>[('proteina', 'NCFS000', 1), ('francisco', 'NP00000', 1), ('ser', 'VSIS3S0', 1), ('bien', 'NP00000', 1), ('calcio', 'NCMS000', 1), ('estar', 'VAIP1S0', 1), ('huevo', 'NCMS000', 1), ('gracia', 'NCFP000', 1), ('bien', 'RG', 1), ('cosa', 'NCFS000', 1), ('ya', 'RG', 1), ('leche', 'NCFS000', 1)]
```

You want to count the number of occurrences of each pair. The `counter` expression does that. The list comprehension formats this as triples.

Answer (score 1):

What specific output do you need? I don't know what exactly do you need to do, but if you want to group items related to same word, you can turn this structure into dictionary and manipulate it later

```
>>> new = {}
>>> for i,j in a: # <-- a = listaPalabras 
        if new.get(i) == None:
                new[i] = [j]
        else:
                new[i].append(j)
```

which will give us:

```
{'francisco': ['NP00000'], 'ser': ['VSIS3S0'], 'cosa': ['NCFS000'], 'ya': ['RG'], 'bien': ['NP00000', 'RG'], 'estar': ['VAIP1S0'], 'calcio': ['NCMS000'], 'leche': ['NCFS000'], 'huevo': ['NCMS000'], 'gracia': ['NCFP000'], 'proteina': ['NCFS000']}
```

and then later on you can do:

```
>>> for i in new:
        if len(new[i]) > 1:
                print "compare {this} and {that}".format(this=new[i][0],that=new[i][1])
```

will print:

```
compare NP00000 and RG #for key bien
```

EDIT:
In the first step, you can also use defaultdict, as suggested by Marcin in the comment, this would look like this:

```
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for i,j in a:
        d.setdefault(i,[]).append(j)
```

EDIT2 (answer to OP's comment)

```
for i in d:
    item = []
    item.append(i)
    item.extend(d[i])
    item.append(len(d[i]))
    result.append(item)
```

This gives us:

```
[['francisco', 'NP00000', 1], ['ser', 'VSIS3S0', 1], ['cosa', 'NCFS000', 1], ['ya', 'RG', 1], ['bien', 'NP00000', 'RG', 2], ['estar', 'VAIP1S0', 1], ['calcio', 'NCMS000', 1], ['leche', 'NCFS000', 1], ['huevo', 'NCMS000', 1], ['gracia', 'NCFP000', 1], ['proteina', 'NCFS000', 1]]
```

Comment: better with a defaultdict

Comment: I don't know, maybe, why do you think so? It's difficult to tell what exactly is needed here.

Comment: Because `defaultdict` exists to replace the if/else in your code.

Comment: The result will be a list of lists that contains 3 elements: the word, the tag, and the number of occurrences of each word(that's why I need to compare their tags if the word exists more than once to see if they are completely different and count them properly ). Sort is not important thou, I think the title of my question is not clear...

Comment: 3 or more elements depending on the tag right? Or do you need to choose one based on some criteria? In case of bien it will have 4 elements. I've edited my answer, hope it helps.

Comment: Thks but in the case of the word 'bien' it should be ['bien', 'NP00000',1],['bien', 'RG',1]. two sub lists counted separately

Answer (score 0):

A purely list-based solution is possible of course, but requires additional looping. If efficiency is important, it might be better to replace `listaPalabras` with a dict.

```
def comparapal(lista):
  listaPalabras=[]
  for item in lista:
     if item[2] in eagles_dict.keys():
        listaPalabras.append([item[1],item[2]])

  last_tt = [None, None]
  for tt in sorted(listaPalabras):
    if tt == last_tt:
      print "Observed %s twice" % tt
    elif tt[0] == last_tt[0]:
      print "Observed %s and %s" % (tt, last_tt)
    last_tt = tt
```

This gives you:
`Observed ['bien', 'RG'] and ['bien', 'NP00000']`

If this does not suit your purposes, please specify your question.

Comment: The result will be a list of lists that contains 3 elements: the word, the tag, and the number of occurrences of each word(that's why I need to compare their tags if the word exists more than once to see if they are completely different and count them properly ). Sort is not important thou, I think the title of my question is not clear...